# Why won't this simple C++ program compile?

Tags: c++

Here is my very simple C++ function:

```
#include <string.h>


void myFunc(void * param)
{
        string command;
}
```

Why isn't it compiling?

```
% CC -c -o testFunc.o testFunc.C
"testFunc.C", line 6: Error: string is not defined.
1 Error(s) detected.
```

Comment: Despite the name, there is no entity defined in the `<string.h>` header with the name `"string"`.

Comment: you most likely want to `#include <string>` and use `std::string command` instead of `string command`.  Also I would make sure that CC is a C++ compiler and not the C compiler.

Comment: why the down votes - its a perfectly good question with a well defined answer

Comment: If you took bits and pieces from all the comments and answers posted here, you might be able to compose an answer worth upvoting.

Comment: I assume the `% more testFunc.C` is the command you used to display the source file. If so, that's not part of the program, and not relevant here. I don't care if you used the Windows `type` or the Unix `cat`, `more`, `less` or whatever.

Comment: @pm100 I didn't downvote, but "why won't this code compile" questions are usually not good. He will get his answer, but it's "too localized" and not likely to help future visitors.

Answer (score 8):

`<string.h>` is from C and defines C string handling functions like `memcmp` and `strcpy`, not the C++ class `string`. In standard C++, the header for that is `<string>`, and the class `string` is in namespace `std`.

Comment: -1: <string.h> is standard C++ (not saying it is recommended over <cstring> or <string>)

Comment: @ThomasEding: Good catch. That header in my mind is `<cstring>` :) Fixed.

Comment: I think you have an extra "and" near the beginning :-)

Comment: @UpAndAdam: :sigh: Man I'm just totally screwing this up :) Actually it was a missing "is" -- fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: No worries! Figured you were going somewhere with that and didn't want to edit myself.

Answer (score 6):

It isn't compiling for exactly the reason it is telling you:

```
Error: string is not defined.
```

Change `<string.h>` to `<string>`.

Also make sure you are using the correct namespace. You can do this by:

```
using std::string;
```

or

```
std::string command;
```

---

**More explanation:**

- `<string.h>` is for C strings in C.
- `<cstring>` is for C strings in C++.
- `<string>` is for C++ `std::string`.

Comment: Either put "using std::string" after the include or just use "std::string" instead of "string"

Comment: `std::string` or `using std::string;` should be prefered over `using namespace std;`.

Comment: @Yakk:  Are you actually using a C++ compiler or are you using a C compiler?

Comment: Compiles, and works, now.